# heating problem - L7805C

Tags: embedded, heat

I'm using a L7805C voltage regulator , to power an SMPS circuit. But its getting heated after 10 min or so , even if I've put a heat sync.

SMPS IC is used to convert +5V to -9V.

Comment: What current is being taken by the SMPS? What dc voltage is fed to the 7805 input?

Comment: Voltage input to the Voltage regulator  - 12V (two wheeler battery). Voltage input to SMPS - 5.08V

Comment: Current to SMPS is required. Clearly the voltage will be 5V because it's a 5V regulator.

Comment: Why are you powering a switchmode with a linear regulator?

Comment: I used to power it the same way earlier,  without any problems.

Comment: Now , even the regulator and SMPS are getting heated , but their functionality is not hampered.

Answer (score 2):

A 7805 will always produce waste heat because it is a linear regulator. This means that current out = current in and, given that it might regulate 7V down to 5V, the power dissipated is 2V * current out. If the current out is 0.5 amps then the power dissipated is 1 watt.

If the voltage in is 12V and the current out is 0.5 amps then power wasted as heat is 3.5 watts and this will fry a 7805 without a heat-sink.

Work it out with the formula: -

Power dissipated by 7805 = \$(V_{IN} - 5V)\times I_{OUT}
\$